# Firestore getProductID cannot be null error

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use the new Firestore released by Firebase in my android app. Unfortunately I keep getting this error when trying to write to the database.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText txtName,txtSurname;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar =  findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    txtName = findViewById(R.id.Name);
    txtSurname = findViewById(R.id.Surname);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

            Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
            user.put("first", "Ada");
            user.put("last", "Lovelace");
            user.put("born", 1815);

            db.collection("users")
                    .add(user)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                            //Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + documentReference.getId());
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            //Log.w(TAG, "Error adding document", e);
                        }
                    });

        }
    });
}
```

This is the error I keep getting. I have added the project to my android app via the assistant. So there shouldn't be an issue.

> Process: damn.testapp, PID: 2622
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FirebaseOptions.getProjectId()
>   cannot be null at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.zze(Unknown Source) at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(Unknown
>   Source) at damn.testapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:44)
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my security rules for the database

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the dependency I am using:

```
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2'
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I had the same problem.
Solved with this in gradle :
3.0.0 to 3.1.0

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you discover this?

Comment: Like you I was searching about an answer. I noticed in an other post with a different question that com.google.gms:google-services was up to 3.1.0. I just tried and saw what happens.

Comment: @sokarcreative thanks man! saved me from putting another hole in the wall!

Answer (score 3):

This failure can happen if you have a google-services.json file but it doesn't have a `project_id` key in the `project_info` section.

This could happen if you're adding Firestore to an existing app with an older google-services.json file. Project ID is a relatively new field in this file, added to support Firestore.

Sign into the Firebase console, find your app in there, re-download the google-services.json file, replace it in your project, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I just did that, also unninstall the app, clear data and cache, and nothing. It still giving me `IllegalArgumentException: FirebaseOptions.getProjectId() cannot be null`

I'm checking my `project_info` and it have the right `project_id`

Comment: Is it possible that you're not using the google-services plugin in your build?

See steps at the bottom of https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?authuser=0#manually_add_firebase

Comment: The problem was my google-services version. I just upgraded it to `3.1.0` and its working

Answer (score 3):

I have

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}
```

and the solution is in the constructor of FirebaseOptions .setProjectId(prjID)

```
    String projectID = "project-id-com";
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApplicationId("1:26000034:android:6d45000000534")
            .setApiKey("AIzaSyAbsrv0000000000eml95vFOs")
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://" + projectID + ".firebaseio.com")
            .setProjectId(projectID)
            .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, options, projectID);
    FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance(projectID);
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(app);

    Map<String, Object> city = new HashMap<>();
    city.put("name", "Los Angeles");
    city.put("state", "CA");
    city.put("country", "USA");

    db.collection("documents")
            .document("example")
            .set(city)
            .addOnSuccessListener(documentReference ->
                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " ))
            .addOnCompleteListener(ab ->
                        Log.d(TAG, "complete: "))
            .addOnFailureListener(e ->
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error adding document", e));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is causing the problem.

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
```

Instead, use it like this:

```
private DocumentReference documentReference = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().document("sampleData/myData");
```

And the save the data like this;

```
    Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
    user.put("first", "Ada");
    user.put("last", "Lovelace");
    user.put("born", 1815);
    documentReference
            .set(user).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "DocumentSnapshot added with ID: " + documentReference.getId());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you modified database security rules in Firebase Console and added the Firestore dependency?

Comment: I have the most up to date dependency and unlocked security rules for the database.

Comment: It doesn't get to that code. The app crashes before that when the document reference is declared.

Comment: Yep that's where it is.

Comment: I still getting the same error just doing `_firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()`

Answer (score 0):

sokarcreative answer did not worked for me. I did this:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with sending the key containing "null" value. Try replacing the key value with empty string "".

Comment: Please give code example of this, doesn't seem to have resolved the issue the way I've tried this